# spring boot maven plugin issues with vscode

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to port my project over from Eclipse into VSCode.  The application will run fine but it won't automatically reload whenever I'm changing the UI.  This works in Eclipse but I can't figure out why VScode won't do it once my application has been launched.

I have the spring boot maven plugin in my pom as below.

```
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
   <plugin>
```

Do I need to add anything to my launch.json that I might be missing? or is there some other configuration change I need to make?

```
    "configurations": [
    {
        "type": "java",
        "name": "Debug (Launch)-Application<comp-man>",
        "request": "launch",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "console": "internalConsole",
        "stopOnEntry": false,
        "mainClass": "com.timeman.Application",
        "projectName": "comp-man",
        "args": ""
    },
    {
        "type": "java",
        "name": "Debug (Attach)",
        "request": "attach",
        "hostName": "localhost",
        "port": 0
    }
]
```

}

Comment: i guess eclipse has support for spring-boot, I haven't use spring-boot with vscode but i'm guessing the support is limited anyway you can check https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html

Comment: Does VSCode automatically to a compile of the changed classes? If not, you have to enable it (i don't use VSCode, so i don't know how to do it). Additionally you have to launch the Spring Boot application with the devtools, as described in the link of neo_lestat, otherwise the agent which is responsible for the reloading, is not registered.